# Preprocessing of input with savedmodel simple_save and tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a simple model, that I have trained and that seems to be working fine now I'd want to use tensorflow serving for which i need savedmodel.

But I don't see a way of specifying any preprocessing to be done to input data with simple_save()

My model:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(
    keras.layers.Embedding(maxAlphabetDictValue + 1, 8, input_length=maxVariableLength))
model.add(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(12))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(len(conventions))  # output layer
```

model = keras.models.load_model("model.h5")

How I run predictions:

```
variable = "test_Adam"
variable = preparePredictionInput([variable], alphabetDict, maxVariableLength)
result = model.predict(variable, steps=1, verbose=1)
```

So the variable above is what I would receive as input or rather pass as input to Serving API and then I'd want to run 'preparePredictionInput' on passed values.

But I can't find an example of how this can be achieved with saved_model.simple_save()

```
sess = keras.backend.get_session()
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, ".", inputs={model.inputs}, outputs={model.outputs})
sess.close()
```

Comment: Any progress with this? I'm having the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Lambda layer at the start of your model. In a lambda layer you can specify a function to transform your input.